# Best approach to Users Profile Images in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and have been diving into many tutorials and online material. I am now beginning to plan/develop my own app. From all the reading I have done I am yet to come across an industry standard way of handling user profile pictures. I have bullet point what I intend to do (below) and would like some suggestions whether this is a good approach and on the right track or whether there is a much better/secure/standard way:

1. add a 'ProfilePhotoPath' column to my User Model/Table of type String, which will hold the location path/name of the photo
2. on sign-up form implement an image upload functionality to upload profile pic and store at specified location (reference in step 1 above)

note: I have come across the 'paperclip gem' and 'imagemagick', is this a better easier approach to what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two better ways to upload profile image using Carrierwave or Paperclip.

If you want to use Carrierwave then refer this tutorial [Image Upload using Carrierwave](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?view=asciicast)

And if you want to go for Paperclip, then refer this links [Upload image using Paperclip video tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip?view=asciicast)

Another link with steps is [Upload profile image using Paperclip](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-install-image-magick-and-setup-paperclip)

Answer (score 0):

Most people use Paperclip or a more robust solution would be Carrierwave.
Both are really good. I would tell you to learn Paperclip first.

It's fairly easy if you're just starting out.

Edit: checkout this link. Click the green 'run' button to see the app.

http://runnable.com/UnnhcBiQoFhwAAEb/how-to-upload-files-using-paperclip-for-ruby-on-rails